# How to create condtional lambda expression for date ranges?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, lambda

In my ASP.net MVC project, I've a search form with a total of 7 search variables. None of them are mandatory, however, at least one should be selected to perform search operation, as shown in the image.

[image: Search Form]

What is the best method to perform search using lambda expression in this scenario since any combination of search parameters can be selected by the user? For now, I'm using a long list of 'if-else if' structures and writing individual lambda expressions for each. Is there a better/ more efficient way?

Update 1:
This is just half of the conditions, and now I've been told that even the 'Date To' for each of the three date criteria are optional, which will increase the list of checks even more. Is this the standard way of doing it?

```
IEnumerable<MyRecord> Request = null;
        if (!status.Equals(""))
        {
            if (deliveryDateFrom == null && caseDateFrom == null && pickupDateFrom == null)
            {
                //only request status
                Request = GetRecord("EquipRequest")
                    .Where(r => r.Status == status);                            
            }
            else if (deliveryDateFrom != null && caseDateFrom == null && pickupDateFrom == null)
            {
                // request status and delivery date
                Request = GetRecord("EquipRequest")
                    .Where(r => r.Status == status && (r.DeliveryDate >= deliveryDateFrom && r.DeliveryDate <= deliveryDateTo));
            }
            else if (deliveryDateFrom == null && caseDateFrom != null && pickupDateFrom == null)
            {
                // request status and case date 
                Request = GetRecord("EquipRequest")
                    .Where(r => r.Status == status && (r.CaseDate >= caseDateFrom && r.CaseDate <= caseDateTo));
            }
            else if (deliveryDateFrom == null && caseDateFrom == null && pickupDateFrom != null)
            {
                // request status and pickup date
                Request = GetRecord("EquipRequest")
                    .Where(r => r.Status == status && (r.PickupDate >= pickupDateFrom && r.PickupDate <= pickupDateTo));  
            }
            else if (deliveryDateFrom != null && caseDateFrom != null && pickupDateFrom == null)
            {
                // request status, delivery date and case date
                Request = GetRecord("EquipRequest")
                    .Where(r => r.Status == status && (r.DeliveryDate >= deliveryDateFrom && r.DeliveryDate <= deliveryDateTo)
                    && (r.CaseDate >= caseDateFrom && r.CaseDate <= caseDateTo));  
            }
            else if (deliveryDateFrom != null && caseDateFrom == null && pickupDateFrom != null)
            {
                // request status, delivery date and pickup date
                Request = GetRecord("EquipRequest")
                    .Where(r => r.Status == status && (r.DeliveryDate >= deliveryDateFrom && r.DeliveryDate <= deliveryDateTo)
                    && (r.PickupDate >= pickupDateFrom && r.PickupDate <= pickupDateTo)); 
            }
            else if (deliveryDateFrom == null && caseDateFrom != null && pickupDateFrom != null)
            {
                // request status, case date and pickup date
                Request = GetRecord("EquipRequest")
                    .Where(r => r.Status == status && (r.CaseDate >= caseDateFrom && r.CaseDate <= caseDateTo)
                    && (r.PickupDate >= pickupDateFrom && r.PickupDate <= pickupDateTo)); 
            }
            else if (deliveryDateFrom != null && caseDateFrom != null && pickupDateFrom != null)
            {
                // request status, delivery date, case date and pickup date
                Request = GetRecord("EquipRequest")
                    .Where(r => r.Status == status && (r.DeliveryDate >= deliveryDateFrom && r.DeliveryDate <= deliveryDateTo)
                    && (r.CaseDate >= caseDateFrom && r.CaseDate <= caseDateTo)
                    && (r.PickupDate >= pickupDateFrom && r.PickupDate <= pickupDateTo));
            }                
        }
```

Comment: You only need 6 `if` statements (one for each condition) (and no `else if` should be necessary)

Comment: Show us (at least some of) your code so we can help.

Comment: Please post your code to give better solution.

Comment: `var query = GetRecord("EquipRequest"); if (status != null) { query = query.Where(x => x.Status == status); } if (deliveryDateFrom != null) { query.Where(x =>  x.DeliveryDate >= deliveryDateFrom); }` etc (one if for each condition)

Comment: Look like **filtering** should be the responsibility of **GetRecord** method. Could you post the code of `GetRecord("EquipRequest")`?

Comment: @Win GetRecord() method receives a string and calls a web service to get all records from the database table for that item. Regardless of whether filtering is done here or in GetRecord(), it has to be done. Implementation would be similar in both cases.

Comment: @SJaka This could make a huge difference in performance if it's calling a web service to get all of the records and then filter. It's better to filter your results in the service and return a minimal amount of data.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is use a function like the following:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> WhereIf<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, bool condition, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    return condition ? source.Where(predicate) : source;
}
```

What it will do is if the bool is true, it will narrow it down by your lambda expression, if it is false, it will just continue.

And used it like so:

```
var whatever = GetRecord("EquipRequest")
    .Where(r.Status == status)
    .WhereIf(deliveryDateFrom != null, r => r.DeliveryDate >= deliveryDateFrom)
    .WhereIf(deliveryDateTo != null, r => r.DeliveryDate <= deliveryDateTo)
    .WhereIf(caseDateFrom != null, r => r.CaseDate >= caseDateFrom)
    .WhereIf(caseDateTo != null, r => r.CaseDate <= caseDateTo)
    .WhereIf(pickupDateFrom != null, r => r.PickupDate >= pickupDateFrom)
    .WhereIf(pickupDateTo != null, r => r.PickupDate <= pickupDateTo)
```

So on and so forth

Answer (score 0):

First I recommend you get [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/), learn it, if you want to experiment with things like this.

Then write something like this LinqPad script and run it to get your Linq statement correct:

```
public class SearchViewModel {
    public DateTime DeliveryDateFrom {get; set;}
    public DateTime DeliveryDateTo {get; set;}
    public DateTime CaseDateFrom {get; set;}
    public DateTime CaseDateTo {get; set;}
    public DateTime PickupDateFrom {get; set;}
    public DateTime PickupDateTo {get; set;}
};



public class Data {
    public DateTime DeliveryDate {get; set;}
    public DateTime CaseDate {get; set;}
    public DateTime PickupDate {get; set;}
};

void Main()
{
    var model = new SearchViewModel();  // insert your model stuff here
    // you can use LinqPad to hook up directly to your project DBContext dll here
    var dataBase = new List<Data>() { 
        new Data() { DeliveryDate = DateTime.Now, CaseDate = DateTime.Now, PickupDate = DateTime.Now }
    };  

    // experiment with Linq statement here
    var result = dataBase.Where(x =>
        (model.DeliveryDateFrom >=  x.DeliveryDate && model.DeliveryDateTo <=  x.DeliveryDate) &&
        (model.CaseDateFrom >=  x.CaseDate && model.CaseDateTo <=  x.CaseDate) &&
        (model.PickupDateFrom >=  x.PickupDate && model.PickupDateTo <=  x.PickupDate)
    );

    result.Dump();
}
```

Comment: mage Thanks for the quick response. I can write lambda and linq expressions. However, I am concerned about the number of if checks required to cover every possible case. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can chain where clause.

```
IEnumerable<MyRecord> query = GetRecord("EquipRequest");
if (!status.Equals(""))
{
    if (deliveryDateFrom.HasValue) 
        query = query.Where(x => x.DeliveryDate >= deliveryDateFrom);
    if (deliveryDateTo.HasValue) 
        query = query.Where(x => x.DeliveryDate <= deliveryDateTo);
}
IEnumerable<MyRecord> result = query.ToList();
```